# simpleXML - cant figure out how to get elements

Tags: php, api, simplexml

Thanks for looking ... I have never used an API before and am stuck. Here is the XML that comes back from the API (changed the values as i dont think it should be public)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
<response>
    <result code="1000">
        <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
    </result>
    <resData>
        <ext-support:lstData xmlns:ext-support="http://www.apitest.co.uk/whapi/ext-support-2.0">
            <ext-support:categoryGroup name="Main Category Name">
                <ext-support:category id="1">Support item 1</ext-support:category>
                <ext-support:category id="2">Support item 2</ext-support:category>
            </ext-support:categoryGroup>
            <ext-support:categoryGroup name="Another Category Name">
                <ext-support:category id="5">Another Support item 1</ext-support:category>
                <ext-support:category id="6">Another Support item 2</ext-support:category>
            </ext-support:categoryGroup>
        </ext-support:lstData>
    </resData>
</response>
</epp>
```

I am using;

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($returned_xml);
```

but cant figure out how to get at the data inside the object.

I basically want to loop through this so I end up with

```
 Main category name
   Support item 1 (id:1)
   Support item 2 (id:2)

 Another category name
   Another support item 1 (id:5)
   Another support item 2 (id:6)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Jason

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it with this (after a few hours of trial and error!)...

```
    foreach ($xml->response->resData->children('ext-support', true)->lstData->categoryGroup as $group)
    {
         echo $group->attributes();
         echo '<br/>';
         foreach ($group->category as $cat)
         {
             echo $cat;
             echo $cat->attributes();
             echo '<br/>';
         }
     }
```

Thanks anyway!